# SQL query to hide bad rows by difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table `s_log` that shown like this

```
id | parent_id | log_time         | s_value
 1 | 1         | 2013-10-09 09:01 | 2.1
 2 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:02 | 9.1 --> hide this
 3 | 1         | 2013-10-09 09:04 | 5.2 --> hide this
 4 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:05 | 4.1
 5 | 1         | 2013-10-09 09:06 | 2.3
 6 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:07 | 4.2
 7 | 1         | 2013-10-09 09:09 | 2.2
 8 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:10 | 4.9
 9 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:11 | 5.7
10 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:12 | 6.3
11 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:13 | 2.3 --> hide this
12 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:14 | 5.8 
13 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:15 | 6.5 
14 | 2         | 2013-10-09 09:16 | 9.5 --> hide this
```

the requirement are:

- not showing any values that has difference more than 1 to previous and next row by parent_id
- bad data only appears before and after 2 data, except for the first and last record

for example when parent_id = 1

```
 2.1 - 5.2 - 2.3 - 2.2
  \ 3.1 \ 2.9 \ 0.1
    BAD   BAD   OK
```

so 5.2 must be hidden

another example when parent_id = 2

```
 9.1 - 4.1 - 4.2 - 4.9 - 5.7 - 6.3 - 2.3 - 5.8 - 6.5 - 9.6
  \ 5.0 \ 0.1 \ 0.7 \ 0.8 \ 0.6 \ 4.0 \ 2.5 \ 0.7 \ 3.0
    BAD   OK    OK    OK    OK    BAD   BAD   OK    BAD
```

what my boss asked was quite impossible..

edit: use PostgreSQL 9.3 if possible

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: what are the rules for the bad data?

Comment: I'd say this requires a bounty or a big paypal donation :P

Comment: @Maureinik PostgreSQL

Comment: @Dementic, bad data is a record have s_value difference more that 1 to its previous and next record

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive query we can compare each row to it's previous one, even if it doesn't have a previous ID (one less).

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
  ( 
     [ID]        INT, 
     [PARENT_ID] INT, 
     [LOG_TIME]  DATETIME, 
     [S_VALUE]   NUMERIC(4, 2), 
     RN          INT 
  ) 

INSERT @tbl 
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER ( 
           PARTITION BY PARENT_ID 
           ORDER BY ID) RN 
FROM   TABLE1 

;WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(4, 2)) AS diff 
         FROM   @tbl 
         WHERE  RN = 1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT T2.*, 
                ABS(CAST(T1.S_VALUE - T2.S_VALUE AS NUMERIC(4, 2))) diff 
         FROM   CTE T1 
                INNER JOIN @tbl T2 
                        ON T1.RN = T2.RN - 1 
                           AND T1.PARENT_ID = T2.PARENT_ID) 
SELECT ID, 
       PARENT_ID, 
       LOG_TIME, 
       S_VALUE 
FROM   CTE 
WHERE  DIFF < 1
```

A working example can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d6d1/10).

If you're using SQL 2012, there is a much easier solution.
Use the `LAG` or `LEAD` functions to get the same results in much shorter and easier code.